# Need an alternative way to use a table name as a function parameter in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Is there any other way to use a table name as a function parameter in PostgreSQL than with Execute?

The problem is the existing statement (taken from a report in openMaint) is long and has a lot of existing variables.

I want to be able to make a general function that can be used for any similar report where all I need to do is pass the different table parameters instead of making a new function for each report. However things will get exceedingly complicated using Execute. Does anyone have any alternatives for me?

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE "ReportData" AS 
SELECT  lang,
    coalesce((SELECT "Description" FROM "Site" WHERE "Id" = site_id), '')::varchar site_descr,
    coalesce((SELECT "Description" FROM "Division" WHERE "Id" = divis_id), '')::varchar div_descr,
    coalesce(cons."Description", '')::varchar consb_descr,
    coalesce(cat."Code", '')::varchar cat_code,
    coalesce(_cm3_translation_lookup_get(cat."Id", lang), '')::varchar cat_descr,
    coalesce(_cm3_translation_lookup_get(scat."Id", lang), '')::varchar scat_descr,
    coalesce(ssite."Description", '')::varchar srcsite_descr,
    coalesce(sdiv."Description", '')::varchar srcdiv_descr,
    coalesce(dsite."Description", '')::varchar dstsite_descr,
    coalesce(ddiv."Description", '')::varchar dstdiv_descr,
    coalesce(to_char(wrmov."Date", 'DD TMMon YYYY'), '')::varchar wm_date,
    coalesce(wmrow."Quantity", 0.00)::numeric wmr_quantity,
    (CASE WHEN site_id IS null THEN
        CASE cat."Code"
            WHEN 'Load' THEN '+1'
            WHEN 'Relocation' THEN '0'
            WHEN 'Unload' THEN '-1'
            ELSE null
        END
    ELSE
        CASE    WHEN (wrmov."SrcSite" IS null OR wrmov."SrcSite" != ALL(sites_set)) AND wrmov."DstSite" = ANY(sites_set) THEN '+1'
            WHEN wrmov."SrcSite" = ANY(sites_set) AND wrmov."DstSite" = ANY(sites_set) THEN '0'
            WHEN wrmov."SrcSite" = ANY(sites_set) AND (wrmov."DstSite" IS null OR wrmov."DstSite" != ALL(sites_set)) THEN '-1'
            ELSE null
        END
    END)::varchar qt_symbol
FROM "GAWrhMovement" wrmov
LEFT JOIN "LookUp" cat ON cat."Id" = wrmov."Category"
LEFT JOIN "LookUp" scat ON scat."Id" = wrmov."Subcategory"
LEFT JOIN "Site" ssite ON ssite."Id" = wrmov."SrcSite"
LEFT JOIN "Division" sdiv ON sdiv."Id" = wrmov."SrcDivision"
LEFT JOIN "Site" dsite ON dsite."Id" = wrmov."DstSite"
LEFT JOIN "Division" ddiv ON ddiv."Id" = wrmov."DstDivision"
JOIN "GAWrhMovementRow" wmrow ON wmrow."WrhMovement" = wrmov."Id" AND wmrow."Status" = 'A'
LEFT JOIN "GAConsumable" cons ON cons."Id" = wmrow."Consumable"
WHERE CASE WHEN site_id IS null THEN true ELSE (wrmov."SrcSite" = ANY(sites_set) OR wrmov."DstSite" = ANY(sites_set)) END 
AND CASE WHEN divis_id IS null THEN true ELSE (wrmov."SrcDivision" = ANY(divis_set) OR wrmov."DstDivision" = ANY(divis_set)) END 
AND wrmov."Status" = 'A'
ORDER BY consb_descr, wrmov."Date";
```

Comment: If you want a dynamic table name, you need dynamic SQL (and thus PL/pgSQL and `execute()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no other way than to use dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE`.